# functions stopped working after appending li child (button)

Tags: javascript

My code was working fine up until I tried appending a button to li for toggling completed to todo. I followed the same method as I used for delete todo li child button(which works), but toggle does not work. In fact it caused many more issues.

Ive attempted to rewrite the code in many different ways. Ive ran the debugger with no avail. Ive re read every line.

```
var todoList = {   
  todos: [],    
  addTodo: function(todoText) {    
    this.todos.push({    
      todoText: todoText,    
      completed: false    
    });    
  },    
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {    
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;    
  },    
  deleteTodo: function(position) {    
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);    
  },    
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {    
    var todo = this.todos[position];    
    todo.completed=!todo.completed;    
  },    
  toggleAll: function() {    
   var totalTodos = this.todos.length;    
    var completedTodos = 0;     
   this.todos.forEach (function(todo) {    
   if (todo.completed===true) {    
    completedTodos++       
}    
   });    
    this.todos.forEach (function(todo) {    
    if (completedTodos===totalTodos) {    
    todo.completed= false    
      } else {    
      todo.completed= true    
      }    
    });    
  }    
};    

var handlers = {    
  addTodo: function() {    
    var addTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('addTodoTextInput');    
    todoList.addTodo(addTodoTextInput.value);    
    addTodoTextInput.value = '';    
    view.displayTodos();    
  },    
  changeTodo: function() {    
    var changeTodoPositionInput =     document.getElementById('changeTodoPositionInput');    
    var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoTextInput');    
    todoList.changeTodo(changeTodoPositionInput.valueAsNumber,     changeTodoTextInput.value);    
    changeTodoPositionInput.value = '';    
    changeTodoTextInput.value = '';    
    view.displayTodos();    
  },    
  deleteTodo: function(position) {    
    todoList.deleteTodo(position);    
    view.displayTodos();    
  },    
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {    
    todoList.toggleCompleted(position);    
    view.displayTodos();    
  },    
  toggleAll: function() {    
    todoList.toggleAll();    
    view.displayTodos();    
  }       
};    

var view = {    
  displayTodos: function() {    
    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');    
    todosUl.innerHTML = '';    
    todoList.todos.forEach (function(todo, position) {    
      var todoLi = document.createElement('li');    
      var todoTextWithCompletion = '';    
      if (todoList.todos[position].completed === true) {    
        todoTextWithCompletion = '(x) ' + todo.todoText;    
      } else {    
        todoTextWithCompletion = '( ) ' + todo.todoText;    
        todoLi.id = position;    
      todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;    
      todoLi.appendChild (this.createDeleteButton());    
      todoLi.appendChild (this.createToggleCompletedButton());    
          todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);    
      }    
    }, this);    
  },    
  createDeleteButton: function () {    
  var deleteButton= document.createElement ('button');    
    deleteButton.textContent= 'Delete';    
    deleteButton.className= 'deleteButton';    
    return deleteButton;    
  },    
  createToggleCompletedButton: function () {    
  var toggleButton= document.createElement ('button');    
    toggleButton.textContent= 'Mark';    
    toggleButton.className= 'toggleButton';     
    return toggleButton;    
  },    
  setUpEventListeners: function () {    
var todosUl= document.querySelector ('ul');    
todosUl.addEventListener ('click', function(event) {    
var elementClicked= event.target;    
  if (elementClicked.className=== 'deleteButton') {    
  handlers.deleteTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));    
      } else if (elementClicked.className=== 'toggleButton'){    
      handlers.toggleCompleted(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));     
      };     
    });    
  }      
};    
view.setUpEventListeners();
```

When the "Mark" button gets clicked, toggleCompleted should take place causing either ( ) TodoText or (x) TodoText should be displayed on ul (depending on boolean value). However, nothing happens. Even when I go through the console, both toggleCompleted and toggleAll do not work. When I run the debugger, it shows that many defined variables are shown as undefined with errors (including the todoList); all the other functions work regardless of the undefined issue(which is also weird).

Comment: 109 lines of code is a bit much, please make it into a [MCVE]

Comment: Im new to stack overflow (and programming) and I dont know where exactly in my code the issue is, thats why I posted it all. Can you please not down vote as nobody is going to help me now... Its supposed to be for lack of research, not a dislike button.....

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, issues started in making the createToggleCompletedButton and adding it in the setUpEventListeners

Comment: what does the part in html code look like? (just to test this part)

Comment: Mister Jojo I appreciate you responding and showing interest in helping. Thankfully someone answered it with the solution. Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not actually rendering the todo element whenever the completed flag is set to true, it simply gets skipped. You'll have to do this:

```
todoList.todos.forEach(function(todo, position) {    
  var todoLi = document.createElement('li');    
  var todoTextWithCompletion = '';  
  if (todoList.todos[position].completed === true) {
    todoTextWithCompletion = "(x) " + todo.todoText;
  } else {
    todoTextWithCompletion = "( ) " + todo.todoText;

  } // <---- insert closing parenthesis here ...

  todoLi.id = position;
  todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createToggleCompletedButton());
  todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);

  // } <---- instead of here

}, this);
```

Comment: Youre amazing! Thank you so much! Why does this do that? I would have never known this